# custom register form for express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I followed a tutorial from :
http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.V5XhRNDJui5

Here how the current registration form look in /routes/index.js

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    res.render('register', { });
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
        if (err) {
          return res.render('register', { error : err.message });
        }

        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
            req.session.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

How do I post below data from the registration form into mongodb :

- address
- nationalid
- telephone
- email

TQ